# Install Linux without desktop but retain wifi drivers and connection configuration?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, installation

Debian installation offers you a terminal-based either UI mode. Both recognize wifi networking and even allow to enter WPA key.

However, I did not find a way to tell the system not to install the desktop but keep wifi connection.

Is there a way to have this more or less out of the box (maybe some other Linux distro?) I mean, if the system manages to recognize hardware and even pass wifi configuration over to the desktop component, it should be possible in the terminal-mode only as well?

Comment: Did you need to install debian on the hard drive without GUI and manage the  wifi connexion from the terminal?

Comment: yes; that without complex troubleshooting with driver etc. The "workaround" has been so far to unsinstall the whole UI stuff after all :)

Comment: Assuming you are installed debian without GUI , first time you need a wired connexion to install the wifi driver (only if the driver isn't included on the linux kernel ) , To connect to a wifi AP it is very easy through `wpa_supplicant` from the terminal

Comment: You didn't tell us what you've tried, but the components needed for WLAN and the components needed for an UI are completely separate, so you should have no trouble installing the former without the latter (unless funny systemd dependencies get in the way, as they have a habit to do).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle this setup but the closest
you can get to a graphical desktop setup is using NetworkManager to
handle your network and setting up stuff using its `nmcli`
(Network Manager Command-Line Interface) tool:

See the state of the radio stuff:

```
# nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 

# nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlan0   wifi      disconnected  --         
eth0    ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

Connect to your Wi-Fi network:

```
# nmcli device wifi rescan
# nmcli device wifi list
# nmcli device wifi connect SSID-Name password wireless-password
```

There, the `SSID-Name` and `wireless-password` is what you're supposed to provide; the rest are keywords for the command, so to connect to
the network "FBI" using the password "hAx0R", you'd use

```
# nmcli device wifi connect FBI password hAx0R
```

(I'd advise you to put an extra space in front of this `nmcli` encantation
to make your `bash` shell not to remember the command in its history file.)

[See more](https://nullr0ute.com/2016/09/connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-command-line-nmcli/).